# How to add items implicitly to a combobox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, c#-4.0, combobox

I have the problem: I can not add new item to the same combobox where clicked one of the comboboxItem. It returns me an InvalidOperationException: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." The only thing that I could find is [this](http://robertbouillon.com/2010/03/16/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute/). I guess this must be the root of my problem, I still use the "comboboxlist" meanwhile I am changing it. But I can not reset the combobox or create a new one. (Although I managed to add new items to the combobox explicitly, f.e. with a button event.)

here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxServers">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="(local)"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="&lt;Browse for more...&gt;" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

here is the event handler in c#

```
 private void ComboBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxServers.Items.Add("test");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: You may want to try an alternate way of doing it.  For instance, how about making the "Browse for more..." ComboBoxItem a StackPanel which has a ToggleButton and a ListBox; when clicked (toggled), show the ListBox.  Or, does it work to hide the extra items, then when "Browse for more..." clicked, make them all visible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the `ComboBox` while handling the event you should set the event handler on the `ComboBox` and not on the `ComboBoxItem`. You will then have to check what `ComboBoxItem` was selected before proceeding.